# How to override a function or variable type in Elixir and Dialyzer?

Tags: elixir, dialyzer, timex

I'm using Elixir and I'm getting a Dialyzer (via Dialyxir) error that says

```
The pattern
variableVdate

can never match, because previous clauses completely cover the type
{:error, :badarg}.
```

Here is the code

```
date = Timex.DateTime.from_seconds(0)

case date do
  {:error, :badarg} ->
    {:error, "Bad Date"}

  date ->
    {:ok, date}
end
```

I believe this is because `Timex.DateTime.from_seconds` has an [incorrect type spec](https://github.com/bitwalker/timex/blob/2.2.1/lib/datetime/datetime.ex#L402).

They define it as

```
@spec from_seconds(non_neg_integer) :: DateTime.t :: {:error, atom}
```

But I *think* it is supposed to be

```
@spec from_seconds(non_neg_integer) :: DateTime.t | {:error, atom}
```

Is there some way to workaround this issue perhaps by overriding the type spec or the `date` type in some way?

For other reasons, I'm unable to upgrade Timex to version 3.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you're calling `from_seconds/1` with a specific value, 0, so the return is not variable. 
My guess is running this with seconds as a passed in variable might work:

```
case Timex.DateTime.from_seconds(seconds) do
  {:error, :badarg} ->
    {:error, "Bad Date"}

  date ->
    {:ok, date}
end
```